# Infinite Bounce

Tags: animation, materials, physics

I have made a soft body sphere that bounces of a plane. Like in real world the sphere bounces back not as high as it has been dropped from. 
Is there a way that the sphere bounces back to its original starting position and thus bounces infinitely?

Thanks

Comment: You can increase "Bounciness" on both the sphere and the plane. Problem is, with a bounciness of 1, the sphere will bounce higher than its starting position. So, you'll need to tweak the values.

Comment: depending on your use case, it might be easier to manually animate the bounce and squish, than leave it to the physics and soft body.

Comment: thanks for the info. what is the parameter that alters the bounciness?